# Bringing other Chef cookbooks into a custom cookbook

Tags: python-3.x, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm in the process of learning Chef to so I can deploy projects built with Python.

I have my own Cookbook where I am writing my own custom recipes.  I've also downloaded the poise-python cookbook.  Both sit in the same "cookbooks" path in my app.

What I am trying to figure out is how do I include the methods from poise-python so I can use them in my custom cookbook?

Thanks,
RB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your dependency in your `metadata.rb` file for your cookbook. Like this:

```
depends 'poise-python'
```

For this particular dependency this is enough to use the custom resources it provides. You should review any dependency's `README.md` for guidance on using it. You can find [`poise-python`'s here](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/poise-python#readme). You should also review [it's dependencies](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/poise-python#dependencies) to be sure you have all of these available (uploaded to your Chef server, or in the cookbooks directory for Chef solo).

Familiarizing yourself with [Policyfiles](https://docs.chef.io/policyfile.html) is recommended for dealing with dependencies at a greater scale.